# promise race when updating a .innerHTML lead to the removal of a previous value ( how to do it properly? )

Tags: javascript, promise, innerhtml

Here is my problem :
 I have 2 concurents functions, I can call them in parallel and they can be excecuted in any order,

I'd like their respective outputs to be displayed in the html
at the time promises are resolved.

however when I use a div.container with a `.replace` method,
the last promise cancel the actions of the previous one.

I wrote 2 update functions :

- `updateContainer()` : (broken)
- `updatePeerid()` : (works fine)

here is my code:

```js
let peerid = getPeerId()
.then(id => { peerid = (typeof(id) == 'undefined') ? 'QmYourIPFSisNotRunning' : id; return peerid })
.then( updateContainer ) // <--- this one doesn't work
//.then( updatePeerId ) // <--- this one does work
.catch(logError);


load(window).then( _ => { // on window load compute the hash of initial mfspath's value
   console.log('// window loaded')
   form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
   inipath = form.elements['mfspath'].value
   console.log('initial path: ',inipath)
   return getMFSFileHash(inipath)
   .then( updateValue(form.elements['hash']) )
   .then(consLog('load.hash: '))
   .catch(logError)
}).catch(consLog('load'))

function updateValue(e) {
   return x => { e.value = x; return x; }
}

function updateContainer(id) { 
   name = 'peerid';

   if (typeof(callback) != 'undefined') {
      callback(name,id)
   } else {
      let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
      for (let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
         let e = elements[i];
         e.innerHTML =  e.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(':'+name,'g'),id)
            //console.log(e.innerHTML)
      }
   }
   return id;
}
function updatePeerId(id) { 
  let e = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].elements['peerid'];
  console.log('peerid: '+id)
  console.log(e.outerHTML)
  e.value = e.value.replace(new RegExp(':peerid','g'),id)
  return id
}

function getPeerId() {
     let url = webui + '/api/v0/config?&arg=Identity.PeerID&encoding=json';
     return fetch(url,{ method: "GET"} )
     .then( resp => resp.json() )
     .then( obj => { return Promise.resolve(obj.Value) })
     .catch(logError)
}

function getMFSFileHash(mfspath) {
   var url = webui + '/api/v0/files/stat?arg='+mfspath+'&hash=true'
   return fetch(url)
   .then( resp => resp.json() )
   .then( json => {
       if (typeof json.Hash == 'undefined') {
         if (typeof(qmEmpty) != 'undefined') { return qmEmpty }
         else { return 'QmYYY' }
       } else {
         return json.Hash
       }
   })
   .catch(logError)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf8>

<!--
 REQUIREMENT:  NEED TO RUN A LOCAL IPFS DAEMON
-->
<div class=container>
<span id=core></span>
<form>
peerid: <input name=peerid value=":peerid" size=47>
<br>mfs: <input name=mfspath value="/my/identity/public.yml">
<br>hash: <input name=hash value="" size=47>
</form>
</div>
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------- -->
<script>
  var webui = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001'
  var qmEmpty = 'bafyaabakaieac'
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/michel47/snippets@6408682/js/essential.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/willforge/jsring/js/ipfs.js"></script>
-->
```

so event though the hash is fetched properly it doesn't show on the screen due to the fact
the e.innerHTML doesn't contained the last version.

how to do it properly, any help would be appreciated.
+Michel

Comment: The first promise that finishes will remove ":peerid" with something else... The next promise will be looking for ":peerid" but it has been replaced! What are you trying to acheive exactly?

Comment: Doing regex replacements on `innerHTML` is just asking for trouble. Doing so while iterating a *live* node collection, trouble squared.

Comment: @Salketer yes I am ware that his is a one time deal once the preplacement is done it "over", which suits my need as these promises are to run only once to load initial values of the form.
I would like to understand what is happenning, is the innerHTML replacement destroy the form.elements ?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that mixing and update via div.container and via form.elements is the culprit; and updating the HTML both with innerHTML xor both with an element.value assignment works

here is the code that works:

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

let peerid = getPeerId()
//.then( updateByName('container','peerid') )
.then( updateValue(form.elements['peerid']) )
.catch(logError);


load(window).then( _ => { // on window load compute the hash of initial mfspath's value
   console.log('// window loaded')
   inipath = form.elements['mfspath'].value
   console.log('initial path: ',inipath)
   return getHash(inipath)
// .then( updateByName('container','hash') )
   .then( updateValue(form.elements['hash']) )
// .then( h => { updateValue_cb(form.elements['hash'],h); return h })
   .then(consLog('hash: '))
   .catch(logError)
}).catch(consLog('load'))

function updateValue(e) {
   return x => updateValue_cb(e,x);
}
function updateValue_cb(e,v) { e.value = v; return v; }

function updateByName(tag,name) {
   return x => updateByName_cb(tag,name,x);
}
function updateByName_cb(tag,name,value) { 
   console.log('updating: '+tag+' :'+name+' /w value: '+value)
   if (typeof(callback) != 'undefined') {
      callback(name,value)
   } else {
      let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(tag);
      for (let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
         let e = elements[i];
         e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(':'+name,'g'),value)
         //e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd',e.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(':'+name,'g'),value))
      }
   }
   return value;
}

function getPeerId() {
     let url = webui + '/api/v0/config?&arg=Identity.PeerID&encoding=json';
     return fetch(url,{ method: "GET"} )
     .then( resp => resp.json() )
     .then( obj => { return obj.Value || 'QmYourIPFSisNotRunning' })
     .catch(logError)
}

function getHash(mfspath) {
   var url = webui + '/api/v0/files/stat?arg='+mfspath+'&hash=true'
   return fetch(url)
   .then( resp => resp.json() )
   .then( json => {
       if (typeof json.Hash == 'undefined') {
         if (typeof(qmEmpty) != 'undefined') { return qmEmpty }
         else { return 'QmYYY' }
       } else {
         return json.Hash
       }
   })
   .catch(logError)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf8>

<!--
 REQUIREMENT:  NEED TO RUN A LOCAL IPFS DAEMON
-->
<div class=container>
<span id=core></span>
<form>
peerid: <input name=peerid value=":peerid" size=47>
<br>mfs: <input name=mfspath value="/my/identity/public.yml">
<br>hash: <input name=hash value=":hash" size=47>
</form>
</div>
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------- -->
<script>
  var webui = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001'
  var qmEmpty = 'bafyaabakaieac'
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/michel47/snippets@6408682/js/essential.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/willforge/jsring/js/ipfs.js"></script>
-->
```

Comment: This will simplify. Some of the code isn't even called.

Comment: indeed I can simplify the code I want to stay close to the inital functionalliy to solve the problem within context, also I was experimenting to see what's work and what doesn't ...
let me isolate the essential such it is easier to grasp for community.

Comment: By substituting for `updateValue(...)`, you can end up with something as simple as `getPeerId()
.then(id => form.elements.peerid.value = id)
.catch(logError);`.

Comment: And `getPeerId()` should simplify to something like `function getPeerId() {
 return fetch(`${webui}/api/v0/config?&arg=Identity.PeerID&encoding=json`, { 'method': 'GET'})
 .then(resp => resp.json())
 .then(obj => obj.Value || 'QmYourIPFSisNotRunning');
}`